# Genshi table loop

Tags: python, genshi

What is wrong with this Genshi template:

```
<html xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/">     
  <head>
    <title py:content="title"></title>
  </head>
  <body>  
    <left>
    <table py: for="i in range(1, len(ctabl))">
        <li py: for="e in ctabl[i]">
            ${e}
        </li> 
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get this error:

> genshi.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 7, column 14 (templates/index2.html, line 7)

Seems that there is something wrong with the table loop... I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Genshi, but their [list of allowed processing directives](http://turbogears.org/2.0/docs/main/Genshi.html#available-processing-directives) do not have any spaces between `py`, the `:`, and the `for`.  Try removing that space.  And anyway, Line 7, Column 14 is on the colon or the space, depending on whether you count from 0 or 1, right?

Comment: This is correct. The "py:" in "py:for" is part of the XML namespace, and comes from the 'xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"'. That declares the "XML namespace" ("xmlns") with "py" as a local abbreviation for "http://genshi.edgewall.org"